# В чем разница в установке переменной с export и без?

Tags: shell, bash

Изучаю файл `~/.bashrc`. Переменные присваиваются двояко:

```
VARIABLE=something
```

или

```
export VARIABLE=something
```

В чем отличие для первого и второго случая?

Comment: Тут есть второй ответ, он более подробный и точный, чем принятый. Возможно, стоит пересмотреть отметку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо за замечание. Поправил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без export переменная видна только в самом shell'е (а не только в скрипте .bashrc). И не видна программам, запускаемым из этого shell'а (если быть точным, переменная видна в том процессе, где определена, и не видна дочерним процессам).

C export переменная будет видна всем программам, запускаемым из shell'а, в котором эта переменная установлена.

В unix'е нет возможности установить значение переменной глобально, для всей системы. В случае с .bashrc оно конечно выглядит как задание глобального значения, но это достигается только за счет того, что .bashrc выполняется перед началом запуска пользовательского окружения. В любом другом месте использование export такого эффекта не даст.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Первая VARIABLE локальна для шелл-скрипта, каковым .bashrc по сути и является. `export` позволяет задать значение этой переменной VARIABLE глобально, для всей системы, а не для конкретно выполняемой копии оболочки или скрипта.Надеюсь, не ошибся :-)